# Jolt transform to put the json content in a field using NiFi

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

My JSON Input

```json
[
  {
    "id": "1234",
    "Status": "null",
    "Expired": "null",
    "First_Name": "null"
  },
  {
    "id": "5678",
    "Status": "null",
    "Expired": "null",
    "First_Name": "null"
  }
]
```

My JOLT Spec

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "id": "[&1].id"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "Status": "null",
        "Expired": "null",
        "First_Name": "null"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Output:

```json
[
  {
    "id": "1234",
    "First_Name": "null",
    "Expired": "null",
    "Status": "null"
  },
  {
    "id": "5678",
    "First_Name": "null",
    "Expired": "null",
    "Status": "null"
  }
]
```

Expected output:

```json
{
  "isInput": true,
  "input": [
    {
      "id": "1234",
      "First_Name": "null",
      "Expired": "null",
      "Status": "null"
    },
    {
      "id": "5678",
      "First_Name": "null",
      "Expired": "null",
      "Status": "null"
    }
  ]
}
```

Can this be done using NiFi **`JoltTransformJSON`**. Like put the JSON content in a field `"input"` and add another `"isInput"` key.

If not should I use replaceText with replacement value

```json
{
  "isInput": true,
  "input": "${input}"
}
```

But, then how should I put output of JoltTransform to `${input}` field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add the following two specs to your chain:

```
{
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "isInput": "isInput",
      "*": "input[]"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "isInput": "true"
    }
  }
```

But it's shorter to just use this chain spec:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "id": "input[&1].id"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "input[]": {
        "*": {
          "Status": "null",
          "Expired": "null",
          "First_Name": "null"
        }
      },
      "isInput": "true"
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

One step of shift step will suffice such as

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "#true": "isInput",
      "@": "input"
    }
  }
]
```

[image]

where `@` sign key will copy all of the content for the current level.